# how to remove everything after a specified character

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i want to remove every thing after `-` sign.

here is my sample `string` : `sahasraadvisoryagency - a service agency`

**my expected output** : sahasraadvisoryagency

**my test cases:**

1. `sahasraadvisoryagency - a service agency`   **output:**  `sahasraadvisoryagency`
2. `chai chai - a tea service`                     **output:** `chai chai`
3. `paani wala + neerwal - a water service`        **output:** `paani wala + neerwal`

i'm trying something like this

```js
var str = 'sahasraadvisoryagency - a service agency';

var newstr = str.replace(/\-/g,'');

console.log(newstr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```js
console.log(
  'sahasraadvisoryagency - a service agency'.split('-')[0]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = 'sahasraadvisoryagency - a service agency';
 var n = s.indexOf('-');
  s = s.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : s.length);
  document.write(s);
```

Would you please check above snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple:

```js
var str = 'sahasraadvisoryagency - a service agency';
var newstr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("-"));
console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex wildcard `.*` for zero or more of any character after your `\-`.  This will strip the - and anything after it.

```js
var str = 'sahasraadvisoryagency - a service agency';

var newstr = str.replace(/\-.*/g,'');

console.log(newstr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.substr()` to get a part of the original string by passing the index you want.

In your case:

`str.substr(0, str.indexOf('-'))`

You may need to check if '-' exists in the first place. Also may need to `trim()` if you don't want the space at the end.